# C# and MySql changing column var

Tags: c#, mysql

I'm making mysql register/login system in c#. I'm able to register and login with it.
I'm verify account with:

```
MySqlConnection conn = new MySqlConnection(db_creds);
            try { conn.Open(); }
            catch { throw new Exception("Can't access database"); }
            MySqlDataAdapter adapter;
            DataTable table = new DataTable();
            string query = "SELECT `Nickname`, `Password` FROM `" + db_table + "` WHERE `Nickname` = '" + nickname + "' AND `Password` = '" + password + "'";
            adapter = new MySqlDataAdapter(query, conn);
            adapter.Fill(table);
            conn.Close();
            if(table.Rows.Count <= 0)
            {
                return false;
            }
            else { return true; }
```

After Nickname and Password I have varchar named active. My question is:
How can I change "active" (only for this user) to 1 when user succesfully logged in? and when logoff change it to 0?

Comment: The most dangerous queries.... ! Beware of SQL Injection

Comment: How can I make it safer?

Comment: It is a bad idea. You should consider that if your application crashes then you remain with a user logged in while it is not. Anyway you should run an update query that sets your field to 1 or 0 as needed. And for the Sql Injection use a parameterized query

Comment: Can you write a example of query that sets it in a safe way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To alter a single row in the table, you need to get it's ID(unique identifier for this table). Let the name for this unique column be `str_Id`, then retrieve this id for the particular user name and password. Then you can update the active state based on this unique identifier.

Another important advise for you is, don't use this type of plain-text queries, which will opens a wide door for SQL Injection. So i strongly recommend you to use parameterized queries as follows;

```
string query = "SELECT Nickname,str_Id  FROM your_table_name" +
               " WHERE Nickname =@nickname  AND Password = @password";
MySqlConnection con = new MySqlConnection();

// Creating parameterized command

MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(query, con);
cmd.Parameters.Add("@nickname", MySqlDbType.VarChar).Value = nickname;
cmd.Parameters.Add("@password", MySqlDbType.VarChar).Value = password;
MySqlDataAdapter adapter = new MySqlDataAdapter(cmd);
DataTable table = new DataTable();

// Collect the details to a DataTable

adapter.Fill(table);
if (table.Rows.Count>0) // Means there is some record found
{
    // Get theUnique ID for the matching record
    string uniqueId = table.Rows[0]["str_Id"].ToString();

    // Update active state for that particular user
    query = "Update your_table_name set active='0' Where str_Id=@str_Id";
    cmd = new MySqlCommand(query, con);
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@str_Id", MySqlDbType.VarChar).Value = uniqueId;
    // Execute command here
}
else
{
    // Print message thet no user found
}
```

Comment: @Steve : Thanks, It was by mistake

Answer (score 0):

When you verify if user exists and if password is correct and return message there you need to add update command for your database.

With that update command you need to update column ACTIVE to 1 but to that user, so you need to use this:

```
UPDATE table_name
SET column1=value1
WHERE some_column=some_value;
```

So in your case

```
UPDATE db_table SET active = 1 WHERE nickname = ' + nickname + '
```

So user now have status of ACTIVE.

Now you need to set it to inactive when he log off, so you do that when he press log off button or when he close the program, but with same principle

```
UPDATE db_table SET active = 0 WHERE nickname = ' + nickname + '
```